# how to carry culture parameter in url as routing parameter not request parameter?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want to create a custom routing system ASP.NET MVC 4 project to make my website multilingual. and I want to carry culture parameter in url like localhost/en/controllerName/actionName. but the problem is when I write for example localhost/home routing engine supposes "home" as culture name. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: routes are top down so just put a matching route to /home before the route which does the localisation

Answer (score 0):

If all your routes will enforce culture parameter, you can use something like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "LocalizedDefault",
    url: "{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { lang = @"(es|en|fr)" }
);
```

If you still want to respond to `localhost/home`, just let the default route after the one above, that way the first one will not match because of the constraints and fall back to the second:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```